# Why does the iteration stop at the first yield?

Tags: python, iterator, generator, yield

I'm trying to walk an AST and yield all the matching nodes. My iteration stops at the first match, instead of going trough all the nodes. What am I missing?

```py
import unittest

test_ast = {
    'body': [
        {
            'type': 'BlockComment',
            'value': 'foo'
        },
        {
            'type': 'LineComment',
            'value': ' bar'
        }
    ]
}


def search_comment(haystack, path=()):
    if isinstance(haystack, list):
        for idx, item in enumerate(haystack):
            yield from search_comment(item, path=path + (idx,))
    elif isinstance(haystack, dict):
        for key, value in haystack.items():
            if key == 'type' and 'Comment' in value:
                yield path
                # why doesn't the execution continue from here?
            yield from search_comment(value, path=path + (key,))


class IteratorTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_search_comment(self):
        expected = [('body', 0), ('body', 1)]
        result = []
        while result.append(next(search_comment(test_ast))):
            pass
        self.assertEqual(expected, result)
```

As you can see, the result returns the first match only.

```
Expected :[('body', 0), ('body', 1)]
Actual   :[('body', 0)]
```

Comment: What does `result.append` return?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are at least two problems here: 1) `result.append` returns `None` regardless of what is appended, so the loop breaks immediately. 2) a loop like that would re-create the iterator every time. If you want to create a list from the contents of the `search_comment(test_ast)` generator, it is much easier than that. All you need is... `list(search_comment(test_ast))`. These are all common problems; I would close the question as a duplicate but I am out of close votes today.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks, that did the trick! Closing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Karl Knechtel answered before, the error lies in the test function:

```
result = []
while result.append(next(search_comment(test_ast))):
    pass
```

changed to

```
result = list(search_comment(test_ast))
```

Comment: There is no need to repeat someone else's answers